# Spring Autowired object in object instantiated with new()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring. I have at work in spring-config.xml this :

```
<bean id="statusEmailSender" class="my.package.email.StatusEmailSenderImpl">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage"/>
</bean>
```

In some classes already defined I see something like this:

```
@Autowired
private StatusEmailSender statusEmailSender;
```

And it works. When I do it in my own class, I get a NullPointerException.
I know the reason: I am creating my class with new():

```
return new EmailAction(config,logger);
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class EmailAction{
@Autowired
StatusEmailSender statusEmailSender;
public EmailAction(...)
{
...
}
}
```

Do you know how I can get around this? This is legacy code, and it's extremely difficult to get around the new EmailAction() call.

Comment: Don't think this can be done without letting spring to instantiate EmailAction Bean through context. You will have to migrate this class to use spring

Comment: Is there a setter for `statusEmailSender` in `EmailAction`?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using ?

Comment: @Serban Stoenescu `EmailAction` is spring bean and you are insantiate its object manually in some legacy code which is not part of spring. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

You want use a spring bean inside a non-spring class(legacy code). In order to do that you need to make the Spring's `ApplicationContext` (which holds `BeanFactory` where spring beans are residing) available to legacy code.

For that you need to create a spring bean something like:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private static ApplicationContext context;

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
    this.context = context;
  }
  public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
  }
}
```

and define this bean inside your Spring configuration file (or if you are using annotation driven, annotate bean with @Component)

```
<bean id="springContext" class="com.util.SpringContext />
```

Since `SpringContext` exposes a static method, the legacy code can access it.for example if the legacy code needs spring bean `EmailAction`, call like:

```
EmailAction emailAction= (EmailAction)SpringContext.getApplicationContext.getBean(EmailAction.class);
```

now the `emailAction` will contain all its dependencies set.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just autowire your EmailAction class when you need it?

EmailAction.java:

```
@Component
public class EmailAction{
 // ...
}
```

WhereYouNeedIt.java:

```
public class WhereYouNeedIt{

@Autowired
EmailAction emailAction;


 // access emailAction here

}
```

Comment: I can't, because the class has just one method, which is static. It looks like this: public class ActionFactory { public static IAction createAction(....) { .... return new EmailAction();
  }}. From my experience, I don't think you can autowire static fields, and in this case, if I try what you suggest, my field would have to be static.